# Making a tic tac toe board in HTML/CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my class I have to make the game of Tic Tac Toe using what I have learned which is HTML/CSS and some javascript. I have not learned arrays, loops, or objects yet. So I am hoping this is possible. What I have learned is functions, variables, and if/else/else if. Basically I don't want to ask you nice people to help me with the entire thing because I don't think anyone would do that and it would take to long. I will, however, say that I have no idea where to even start but hopefully I can figure it out. What I do need help on however is setting up the actual board. Do you think I could do something in HTML for setting up the board? Like using the table, th, and tr elements? Or would CSS be better? Thanks a bunch to the people that help!

Comment: Specific questions only.

Comment: I believe I was being specific. I was wondering how to make the board for tic tac toe. Where to start and etc

Comment: Use a table with 3 rows and three columns.

Comment: alright so kind of like table th tr tr tr /th /table kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a table that would help.

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Css:

```
td {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As rpax said,

Use a table with the number of rows you want and the number of columns.

Another suggestion I have for game programming in general is draw it out and write every action possible for all characters down. It may even be a good idea to brainstorm ways to do these tasks on paper. The main thing is, WRITE IT OUT. This will make sure you have a saved plan and you can always change it later.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I heard writing it out is always better, but to be honest I just don't know how to go about it. Like in my head I am thinking about what I want to do and how to do it. So maybe just apply that to paper?

Comment: Yes. It will help so much to write it down. It just helps to have a visual really...

Answer (score 1):

I would create a div in each cell with an id and an onclick function.

Maybe you could do something like

```
var a =1 ;

function dosomething(){
if(a=1){
   document.getElementById('').innerHTML='x';
}else{
   document.getElementById('').innerHTML='O';
}
a=0;
}
```

Comment: Oh alright. That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much